# I can't import an SQL database into EasyPHP

Tags: php, sql, database, import, easyphp

Absolute beginner to programming here. I made an SQL based database on a program called EasyPHP on one PC and I exported it(file extension:'.sql'). I downloaded EasyPHP onto my PC, different from the one I made the database in, and I tried to import the database I made earlier however, I'm getting an 'Error 1046: No database selected'. 
I really don't understand how this is happening. I checked the database in Notepad and it seems fine - I have my data fields defined and all my records are intact.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you start by posting your code

Comment: @ Fred -ii- I don't have any code. All I have is a database called 'userdata.sql'. I went to the 'Import' tab in PHPmyadmin, chose my file and clicked 'Go'. Then I got an error saying '1046:No database selected. '

Comment: well as stated in the answer below, you need to first create a database, then a table associated with the database, having data in there, then being able to export/import.

Comment: @ Fred -ii-  Hmm. I went to the console and I typed in 
CREATE DATABASE userdata;
and then I imported userdata.sql and it seemed fine now. Has it worked?

Comment: Seems to. Look inside if you've any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import doesn't create the database for you.  So, you need to create a new database first, then click into it, then do the import.

If the EasyPHP on your new computer doesn't have a database in it already the import has nothing to import into.  This has thrown me a few times as well.  When doing an export and then a subsequent import, a database isn't created for you.

Depending on your PHPMyAdmin version, you're likely to see a `Databases` tab up the top.  Click it.  You should then be able to choose a database name, then click `Create Database`.  The new database should now appear in the list on the left.  Click it, then you can go to the `Import` tab and import your `.sql` file.

Comment: But the thing is I don't need a new database as I have already made one. This is what I'm trying to import. Or are you suggesting I make a dummy database and then try to import?

Comment: @Is9 Importing an exported database won't create the database when you import it into a new instance of EasyPHP

Comment: @br3nt Your answer is better now, as I felt it was rather short on information at first. Again, that isn't my downvote.

Comment: @br3nt I'll upvote later on tonight. If that downvote still exists and was retracted (by whoever), you'll see only 0 rather than a 1. Once you see the upvote, click on the number (if you don't know this) and you'll see both a -1 and a +1. *Cheers* Glad to see the green tick ;-)

Comment: Cheers @Fred. I do get the downvote at the time it was given lol (whoever gave it), but I'm definitely not one to leave an answer in a dodge state... I still edit my answers from years back lol.

Comment: @ls9, thanks for the upvote, and glad I could help.  All the best on your journey into developerhood.

Comment: @br3nt haha i should be thanking you - I'm so glad there are people like you on sites like stack overflow!